# Assign Holo theme to custom button (LinearLayout)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-resources

I am trying to assign the Holo theme to a custom button I made using LinearLayout:

I am using

```
 android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark"
```

to get the system Holo theme. Since that resource is not public, I copied

```
btn_default_holo_dark.xml
```

in my drawable folder, but still `btn_default_holo_dark.xml` references other private resources I am not able to find and copy...

Here is btn_default_holo_dark.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

I am not able to find those resources in the "platform" folder. Where are they?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please check in drawable folder inside the res folder.

Comment: What! btw, this must be a comment.

Comment: They are not there. Only `btn_default_holo_dark.xml`

Comment: @Amit do you have those files in your Android drawable folder? The ones specified in the selector?

Comment: There may be a drawable-v12 folder. Please check inside this.

Comment: @Mirko, Yes I have put these files in separate drawable folder.

Comment: @Mirko, Check this 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/